# Rails ActiveRecord...how make a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

sorry for my beginner question but i'm trying to learn RoR.
In Rails 3.2 i've declared:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :description
   has_many :subprojects
end


class SubProject < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :id_name, :description, :num_alloc, :project_id
   belongs_to :projects
end
```

How can i show, in a view, a table with the attributes id_name, num_alloc (from SubProject) and name (from Project)

How can i make the join?
In the controller, if i make:

```
@results=  SubProject.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN.......)
```

this, return only the SubProject attribute right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thing called eager loading. When you make a query with a join, and create the objects, these associations are prepopulated. For example:

```
@results = SubProject.joins(:project)
```

In your view, or any other place, if you call the project object inside subproject, you will have direct access to its content, without making another query.

```
@results.each do |r|
  puts r.project.name # The project is prepopulated from the db
end
```

If you don't care about performance, you can just fecth the subprojects and for each one of them query the project inside.

```
@results = SubProject.all

@results.each do |r|
  puts r.project.name # This will make other query
end
```

Comment: Ok...but one question: if i want an object that contains some attribute from the SubProject and Project model? With the join i want select some attribute from the Project and Subproject model

Comment: The `r` is an `SubProject` object. When you make a join, in memory you will have all attributes from `SubPoject` and the attributes from `Project` associated with it.